# Ordenação por campo de join com linq no MySql (C#, MVC)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
query = from p in db.pessoa
        join f in db.pessoa_origem on p.Pessoa_Origem_Id equals f.Id
        join s in db.pessoa_status on p.Pessoa_Status_Id equals s.Id
        join c in db.contato on p.Id equals c.Pessoa_Id
        select p;
```

E eu quero ordenar pela `c.data`.

A cardinalidade da relação entre pessoa e contato é 1 : n. Ou seja, uma pessoa pode ter 0 ou n contatos.

Quando eu uso o código:

```
query = query.OrderByDescending(u => u.contato.Count > 0 ? u.contato.OrderByDescending(t => t.Id).FirstOrDefault().Data : null);
```

Funciona, porém, ele está pegando o maior `Id` dentre os contatos para ordenar pela data dele. O que preciso é pegar o contato com a maior data e ordenar pela data. Porém, o seguinte trecho não funciona:

```
query = query.OrderByDescending(u => u.contato.Count > 0 ? u.contato.OrderByDescending(t => t.Data).FirstOrDefault().Data : null);
```

Alguém poderia ajudar em como resolver este problema?

Comment: O que tu quer dizer com "o seguinte trecho não funciona"? Não compila ou não se comporta como tu quer?

Comment: Pelo que deu pra entender, tu quer que seja retornado um objeto `Pessoa` e um `DateTime` (ou `DateTime?`) referente ao último contato desta pessoa. Primeira coisa que tu precisa ver é essa condição ternária no final da última query, porque se `db.contato.data` for do tipo `DateTime`, tu não podes fazer essa condição retornando `null`

Comment: Oi Jéferson! Ele compila, mas retorna com lista vazia e dá erro... É que eu preciso ordernar o resultado... Por exemplo: Pessoa: Joãozinho Contatos: 15/03/2015 e 17/03/2015 Pessoa: Mariazinha: Contatos: 14/03/2015 e 16/03/2015 No resultado, se ordenado por data crescente deveria aparecer: Mariazinha - 16/03/2015 Joãozinho - 17/03/2015 Mas se ordenado por data decrescente, deveria aparecer: Joãozinho - 17/03/2015 Mariazinha - 16/03/2015 Essa ordenação que eu preciso colocar... mas no select, deve vir o contato, cuja a data seja a maior...

Comment: Eu respondi seu questionamento, só fiquei com uma duvida mas, na verdade só é um reforço, as pessoas que não tiverem contato não vão aparecer nessa seleção, Ok?

Answer (score 1):

Tem uma relação de *Pessoas* para *Contatos* com [cardinalidade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinalidade_(modelagem_de_dados)) ***1:N***, ou seja, uma *Pessoa* **pode ter nenhum ou vários** *contatos*.

Layout das Entidades:

***Entidade Pessoa:***

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }    
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Contato> Contatoes { get; set; }

    public Pessoa()
    {
        Contatoes = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Contato>();
    }
}
```

***Entidade Contato***

```
public class Contato
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Data { get; set; }

    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
}
```

---

*Vou reproduzir a sua dúvida de selecionar somente o **contato** com a maior **data**, segue abaixo os dois exemplos:*

***Ascending (Ascendente)***

```
var query = (from p in db.Pessoas
             join c in db.Contatoes on p.Id equals c.PessoaId
             group p by new { p.Id, p.Nome, Data = p.Contatoes.Max(x => x.Data) } into g
             orderby g.Key.Data ascending
             select new
             {
                 g.Key.Id,
                 g.Key.Nome, 
                 g.Key.Data                                  
             }).AsQueryable();

var result = query.ToList();
```

---

***Descending (Descendente)***

```
var query = (from p in db.Pessoas
             join c in db.Contatoes on p.Id equals c.PessoaId
             group p by new { p.Id, p.Nome, Data = p.Contatoes.Max(x => x.Data) } into g
             orderby g.Key.Data descending
             select new
             {
                 g.Key.Id,
                 g.Key.Nome, 
                 g.Key.Data                                 
             }).AsQueryable();

var result = query.ToList();
```

**Dica:** no final do seu `joins` introduz a parte **group by** igual está no meus dois exemplos.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar Where com Max, porém, você não precisa ordenar uma lista por data se haverá somente uma data na lista.

```
query = query.Where(
    w => 
        w.contato.data == query.Max(
            m => 
                m.contato.data
         )
)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, Leandro! Mas é que eu preciso ordernar o resultado...
Por exemplo:
Pessoa: Joãozinho
Contatos: 15/03/2015 e 17/03/2015

Pessoa: Mariazinha:
Contatos: 14/03/2015 e 16/03/2015

No resultado, se ordenado por data crescente deveria aparecer:
Mariazinha - 16/03/2015
Joãozinho - 17/03/2015

Mas se ordenado por data decrescente, deveria aparecer:
Joãozinho - 17/03/2015
Mariazinha - 16/03/2015

Essa ordenação que eu preciso colocar... mas no select, deve vir o contato, cuja a data seja a maior...